# Getting different "Layer Errors" every time for the same code in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, classification

I am running a classification code and getting different errors every time.

`classification: Layer error: The service is currently unavailable.`

`classification: Layer error: Computation timed out.`

`classification: Layer error: Earth Engine capacity exceeded.`

I may have too many training pixels but I remember getting results with the exact same code before. What may be the problem?

link for my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c40e833eb6fdd2bc89f8b164d3f7b3c

code itself:

```
// Import country boundaries feature collection.
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
// Apply filter where country name equals turkey.
var turkeyBorder = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Turkey'));

var cloudyImage = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20190427T083601_20190427T083603_T36SVJ');

// Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();

var qa = cloudyImage.select('QA60');

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
  
  
///august
    var sent8 = ee.ImageCollection(s2
   .filterDate("2019-07-27", "2019-08-03").filterBounds(turkeyBorder));
var cloudMasked8 = sent8.filterBounds(turkeyBorder).map(maskS2clouds);

var median8 = cloudMasked8.median();


///may2 
    var sent52 = ee.ImageCollection(s2
   .filterDate("2019-05-01", "2019-05-31").filterBounds(turkeyBorder));
var cloudMasked52 = sent52.filterBounds(turkeyBorder).map(maskS2clouds);

var median52 = cloudMasked52.median();
median52 = median52.updateMask(median8)

///july
    var sent7 = ee.ImageCollection(s2
   .filterDate("2019-06-27", "2019-07-27").filterBounds(turkeyBorder));
var cloudMasked7 = sent7.filterBounds(turkeyBorder).map(maskS2clouds);

var median7 = cloudMasked7.median();
median7 = median7.updateMask(median8)


///june
    var sent6 = ee.ImageCollection(s2
   .filterDate("2019-06-01", "2019-06-30").filterBounds(turkeyBorder));
var cloudMasked6 = sent6.filterBounds(turkeyBorder).map(maskS2clouds);

var median6 = cloudMasked6.median();

median6 = median6.updateMask(median8)

    var sent1 = ee.ImageCollection(s2
   .filterDate("2019-10-01", "2019-11-30").filterBounds(turkeyBorder));
var cloudMasked1 = sent1.filterBounds(turkeyBorder).map(maskS2clouds);

var median1 = cloudMasked1.median();
median1 = median1.updateMask(median8)

//may
    var sent5 = ee.ImageCollection(s2
   .filterDate("2019-05-01", "2019-05-31").filterBounds(turkeyBorder));
var cloudMasked5 = sent5.filterBounds(turkeyBorder).map(maskS2clouds);

var median5 = cloudMasked5.median();
median5 = median5.updateMask(median8)


//yearly
    var sent19 = ee.ImageCollection(s2
   .filterDate("2019-01-01", "2020-01-01").filterBounds(turkeyBorder));
var cloudMasked19 = sent19.filterBounds(turkeyBorder).map(maskS2clouds);

var median19 = cloudMasked19.median();
median19 = median19.updateMask(median8)



//calculate NDVI
var med8_ndvi = median8.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var med52_ndvi = median52.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var med7_ndvi = median7.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var med1_ndvi = median1.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var med6_ndvi = median6.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);



//add all bands to august image
median8 = median8.addBands(med8_ndvi); //works
median8 = median8.addBands(med7_ndvi); //works
median8 = median8.addBands(med52_ndvi); //works
median8 = median8.addBands(med6_ndvi)
median8 = median8.addBands(med1_ndvi);
median8 = median8.addBands(median5);
median8 = median8.addBands(median1); 
median8 = median8.addBands(median7);


//classification
 var classNames =
 urban_tr.merge(forest).merge(water).merge(baresoil).merge(TRARPA).merge(bugday)
 .merge(ayc_tr).merge(ahashas).merge(tutun).merge(nohut_tr)
 .merge(pamuk).merge(yoncaek).merge(sekerek).merge(sekerek2).merge(baresoil_col)
.merge(misir_ektr).merge(misir_ektr2).merge(bugdaydoguek).merge(forestek_tr)
.merge(patates_val).merge(hashas).merge(yonca).merge(steppe_forest_tr).merge(steppe_tr)
.merge(mercimekdogu_tr).merge(mercimekbati_tr).merge(fig_tr).merge(pamukek_tr)
.merge(bugdaydogu_tr).merge(arpasag_tr).merge(arpakuzey_tr).merge(misirbati)
.merge(misirdogu).merge(patatesbati).merge(aycbati_tr).merge(aycdogu_tr).merge(celtik_tr).merge(bugdaybati_tr).merge(baresoil2)
.merge(urbantr3).merge(sera).merge(urbantr2).merge(sera2);

  var bands = [
'B1_1',  'B2_1', 'B4_1','B5_1','B6_1','B8_1','B8A_1','B9_1','B11_1',
'B1',   'B2',  'B4',   'B5',    'B6',   'B8',   'B8A', 'B9',  'B11', 
 'B1_2', 'B2_2','B4_2', 'B5_2','B6_2','B8_2','B8A_2','B9_2','B11_2',
'B1_3','B2_3','B4_3', 'B5_3','B6_3','B8_3','B8A_3','B9_3','B11_3',
 'nd','nd_1' ,'nd_2' ,'nd_3'  ,'nd_4'
];
  
     
    var training = median8.select(bands).sampleRegions({
    collection: classNames, 
    properties: ['landcover'], 
    scale: 10,
    tileScale: 16,
    geometries:true
    });
 

//make the classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.svm().train({
  features: training,
classProperty: 'landcover',
inputProperties: bands});

//Run the classification
var classified = median8.select(bands).classify(classifier);

//Display classification
Map.addLayer(classified,{min: 1, max: 29, palette:['#1e7419', '#0d3fb1','#594527','#c39755','#b83ef6','#c30303','#ff7938','#ffffff','#79ff69','#ffee23','#ff5ccd','#7a288e','#b5b735','#282828','#fcc87a','#8ff7fc','#8ff7fc','#27cba5','#b83ef6','#c30303','#ffee23','#ffee23','#fcc87a','#b5b735','#b5b735','#ff8eec','#b83ef6', '#7d908d','#b7edad']},'classification');
```

Answer (score 1):

One cause for an error message may be the use of the deprecated svm classifier. The replacement classifier is libsvm.

```
var classifier = ee.Classifier.libsvm().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands});
```

https://groups.google.com/g/google-earthengine-announce/c/rCu4FP_Cn08/m/DqC192X9BAAJ?pli=1

After switching the classifier the script ran without issue. Using the first 10 training feature classes results were computed and displayed in about 5 minutes. When using all ~40 training feature classes you may run into memory issues. If that is the case you may want to tile up the study area, or explore other memory saving techniques. The debugging guide might be helpful if you are still getting layer errors. If your computations are timing out you may need to export the classification instead of displaying it on the map.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging

[image]